# Does Yahoo! have sub email addresses like Gmail?

Tags: yahoo-mail

I know that with Gmail they have sub-addressing, which they call plus addressing, and you can enter myaddress+anythingelse@gmail.com and it will be sent to myaddress@gmail.com and tell you it was sent to that address.

Does Yahoo! have anything like this or not?

Sending an email to myaddress+customstring@yahoo.com doesn't work, nor does myaddress.customstring@yahoo.com.

Answer (score 14):

In Yahoo Mail Plus<sup>*****</sup> you can create temporary (disposable) email addresses. The setup is not automatic but must be done in advance.  A temporary address will not reveal your actual Yahoo email address.

> ##### Yahoo Help:
> [Create, use, edit, or delete temporary email addresses in Yahoo Mail](https://help.yahoo.com/kb/SLN28815.html)
>
> A temporary email address is a disposable email address that allows you to receive and send emails without disclosing your permanent email address and can be used to sign up for websites or newsletters that you don't trust.
>
> If one of these addresses gets too much spam, for example, simply delete the address.
>
> They consist of 2 parts, a "base name" and a "keyword" (basename-keyword@yahoo.com) and you can create up to 500 of them at a time.

## Instructions

1. Click **Settings** <sup>[image: (Gear icon]</sup> | click **More Settings** <sup>[image]</sup>.
2. Click **Mailboxes**.
3. Click **Add** next to "Temporary email addresses."
4. In the "Set base name" field, enter an available basename
   <sup>**- Once this is set it can't be changed**</sup>
5. Click **Next**.
6. [Optional] Add a keyword and a description.
   Click **Save**.

---

<sup>*****</sup> Temporary email addresses are only available to Yahoo Mail Plus subscribers and users with existing basenames and temporary addresses.